# Spring boot method parameter argument custom validation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-validator

http://www.bbenson.co/post/spring-validations-with-examples/

In the above example custom validation is implemented for request body.

How can the same can be done for request parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator) instead.

Also, to validate request parameter instead of request body, you just need to change the element type in the constraint classes to `ElementType.PARAMETER`.

Comment: Please be avoid link only answers.